# Save date without time in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a DateTimePicker in C# and in the database I have a datetime column.

I've set dd/MM/yyyy as properties of the DateTimePicker but it saves mm/dd/yyyy in the database with the time at 00:00:00.000.

I want to coordinate this DateTimePicker with the column data and I don't want to show the time in the database.

How do I do that?

Comment: The _display format_ of the datetimepicker has nothing to do with the a database field of type DateTime. You should read the DateTimePicker Value property and store it in the database field through an appropriate parameter

Comment: You can use the convert() to convert it to your desired style and then store it as nvarchar,

Comment: Use a [DATE column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx), then: no time can/will be stored. (However, storing the date only can be problematic as all timezone/offset information is lost.)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a `date` type, therefore even if the time portion is sent to SQL Server, SQL Server will only store the date portion. For example:

```cs
// CREATE TABLE DateStorage
// (
//     Dates date
// )

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
// now.ToString() ->  2013-05-24 09:39:00.0000000+00:00

// ---- INSERT ------
Db.Insert("DateStorage", now);

// Dates
// --------------
// 2013-05-24

// ----- READ ----- 
DateTime date = Db.Read("DateStorage").Rows[0]["Dates"] as DateTime;
// date.ToString() => 2013-05-24 00:00:00.00000 +00:00
```